# Microsoft Office 365 Sharepoint issue

Tags: web-part, office-365, anonymous-authentication

When I am logged in through the edit mode my web part (Summary link webpart) displays fine. However when logged out the Summary link webpart displays the error below:

> Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.
>
> Correlation ID:e257e69c-4088-1000-abd0-78be016b1557"

- Extra information: The template is a custom template, however it has been fine until recently. There has been no changes to the site or environment. The issue has occurred before however resolved itself.
- Anyone know how you can investigate on the colleration ID through Office 365

Answer (score 4):

You're only option is to contact Microsoft Support in a new service request from the Office 365 Admin Center with your Correlation ID.

Ref: [How to find more Info on Correlation ID for Office 365 SharePoint Online site](http://curah.microsoft.com/72701/how-to-find-more-info-on-correlation-id-for-office-365-sharepoint-online-site)

[image]

These are your [support channels in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/support-options-in-Office-365-32a17ca7-6fa0-4870-8a8d-e25ba4ccfd4b).

Comment: Thanks Benny. Had a feeling it was leaning towards that way.

Comment: @Andr Glad I could help. If this answered your question, mark it as accepted so other users may find it in the future having the same issue.